Innodb fulltext search index broken / not updating
I have a table with a fulltext search column that was apparently broken and a regular query I run was not producing expected results. After quite a bit of tinkering and head scratching I decided to try rebuilding the entire table:
OPTIMIZE TABLE `po_search`;

This got me the expected response:

Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead

Afterward my queries started returning expected results again. While I realize this may be very difficult to debug without any kind of MCRE, I'm hoping someone might be able to make an educated guess about what kinds of factors would lead to a defunct fulltext index.

The message about OPTIMIZE TABLE being not supported is misleading. Obviously it is supported, and it does change the table. I tried to report this as a bug, but it was rejected. You can read it here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108101

@BillKarwin - be that as it may, I'm familiar with this behaviour so it's normal to me.

Some discussion in the comments led me to understand that the problem with my index arose from some settings that were changed. In this case specifically innodb_ft_min_token_size which was altered after the database was imported. There are a handful of other variables at play here which are all documented in the following section about Rebuilding InnoDB Full-Text Indexes:

For the changes to take effect, FULLTEXT indexes must be rebuilt after modifying any of the following full-text index variables: innodb_ft_min_token_size; innodb_ft_max_token_size; innodb_ft_server_stopword_table; innodb_ft_user_stopword_table; innodb_ft_enable_stopword; ngram_token_size. Modifying innodb_ft_min_token_size, innodb_ft_max_token_size, or ngram_token_size requires restarting the server.

Thanks to @nbk for pointing me in the right direction!
